# Limit input rows with LOAD DATA INFILE in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv, input, pdo

So, here is my question. I have csv file with 130.000 rows (give or take) and I was wondering if it is possible to somehow limit input to only first two rows? I did manage to successfully import file using this block of code:

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'http://localhost/00_VJEZBA/ROK_DEUTCH/csv/wlan_search.txt'
INTO TABLE `test_rok`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(`update_time`,`gefundener`,`conn`,`dbm`,`kod`,`kod`,`mhz`,`value_1`,`value_2`,`value_3`,`dbm_2`)";

$db = connectPDO();

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();
```

and adding

`[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true]` into my connection

and as I said, it works fine but I was wondering is it possible to somehow limit input data? I've read somewhere that it can't be done with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` what's my alternative on that matter?

Comment: Why not trying by taking intermdiate file which holds only 2 rows from your source file

Comment: @Ajay thank you but can you be more precise?

Comment: Do you know php filesystem functions like fopen, fread?

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes, I have heard it. Seems like interesting idea, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case only I needed to test a load of a file with about 3 million records. Using Ajay's comment above, I did "more filename.txt", copied 5 records and pasted into a test file then loaded that. +1 Ajay.